# What's the meaning of "few-unique" at sorting?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

All.

http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/quick-sort-3-way

At the above site, the quick sort 3-way partition algorithm, I found 4 different cases.
I understand random, nearly sorted, reversed case. 
But what's the "few unique"??? It means big integer key??
Can you please elaborate?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, I think few unique means: even if you have a huge array, the set of possible values is quite small. This also means there are many duplicates.

Example: 3, 10, 50, 10, 10, 3, 10, 3, 50, 3, 50, 50, 3, 10, 10, 50, 3, 3, 10, 50, 50, 3 ...

The set of distinct/unique values is `{3, 10, 50}`, quite small, even if the data collection is a lot bigger.

If you intend to sort the array, you can simply do a single scan where you count occurences of values:

```
3 : 8 occurences
10: 7 occurences
50: 7 occurences
```

Then sorting is trivial: just put 3 times '8', 7 times '10' and 7 times '50'. If you have other columns, just counting occurences is not enough, you have to build an index, but the idea is the same.